# YouTube IFrame API with existing IFrame failing to run callbacks

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

Somewhat related to:
[YouTube IFrame API doesn't always load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986647/youtube-iframe-api-doesnt-always-load)

But different in that I AM loading the YouTube script per instructions.  Note, in my source, the iframe is ABOVE the script block in the load order.  I based this off of these instructions (below).  The example works fine if I'm on that page, but doesn't seem to work for me when I put the code on mine.  I'm sure I'm missing something really simple but I'm to be missing it.  Thanks!

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
//Console shows this script is loading

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    console.log("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady", arguments);   //This shows in console

    player = new YT.Player('js_youTubeFrame', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    console.log("onPlayerReady",event); //Never triggers
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log("onPlayerStateChange", event);  //Never triggers
    if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        console.log("YouTube Video is PLAYING!!");  //Never triggers
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="js_youTubeContainer" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe id="js_youTubeFrame" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/u3A7bmEOtaU?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to load a Youtube Video by his API, is following this sintaxis:

```
<div id="video-youtube"></div>

<script id="youtube-tracking-script">

    var youtubeVideoId = 'u3A7bmEOtaU'; // replace with your own video id

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementById("youtube-tracking-script");
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var video;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        video = new YT.Player('video-youtube', {
            height: '352',
            width: '100%',
            videoId: youtubeVideoId,
            playerVars: {rel: 0, showinfo: 0},
            events: {
                'onStateChange': videoPlay
            }
        });
    }

    function videoPlay(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            console.log("YouTube Video is PLAYING!!");
        }
         if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
            console.log("YouTube Video is PAUSED!!");
        }
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            console.log("YouTube Video is ENDING!!");
        }
    }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t4qwfk0d/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion!  That's essentially the same as what I have - the only difference between your suggestion and what I'm doing is that I'm using a pre-existing iframe rather than dynamically rendering it via the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady callback.  The way I'm doing it is considered supported based on the documentation.  Otherwise, your code is effectively identical.  Nevertheless, I gave it a try and... nothing.  The player didn't load.  I see it working in JSFiddle.  I'm at a total loss.

Comment: Update:  While putting your code in failed, when I took my existing code, added the videoId parameter to the Player method, turned the iframe into a div (I learned doing so causes the iframe to inherit classes from the div, by the way - very good to know!) and ran it again... it worked perfectly.  So weird.  While your code didn't work for me, it led to my solution, so I'll give you the answer on it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your `<iframe> </iframe>` to `<div id= "js_youTubeFrame"> </div>`, in my case it works.

I think that Youtube Iframe Api needs that div to convert it on iframe after.